# Doctrine Inheritance: find all children of a table

Tags: inheritance, doctrine, concrete-inheritance

I have a question about Table Inheritance in Doctrine. for an example I'll use 3 tables:

```
Notification:
  columns:
    id
    is_viewed

NotificationLike:
  columns:
    like_id
  inheritance: { type: concrete, extends: Notification }

NotificationComment:
  columns:
    comment_id
  inheritance: { type: concrete, extends: Notification }
```

As you can see, there is a parent table `Notification` and two child tables `NotificationLike`, `NotificationComment` that use concrete inheritance to extend the parent table.

I want to get all the Notifications. how can i do it without some kind of JOIN?

If i try `Doctrine_Core::getTable('Notification')->findAll()` i get 0 records.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm...strange. I have never done concrete inheritance, but with single table inheritance it definitely works. Should work with concrete as well. Maybe the Notification class is marked abstract and can't have any instances. Just a guess

Comment: Each sub-class has to have a id with FK referencing parent's class id ?